# is display property animation in SVG additive?

Tags: firefox, svg, opera, svg-animate

According to the [svg Animate Element document](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#AnimateElement)   animate is additive; but when I am trying to use 2 `animate tag` with `attribute name=display` , I am getting only the effect of later one in firefox 23.0 and opera 12.15, here is [My svg file](http://jsfiddle.net/swarnendu/JmjEZ/);

and Here is two animate tag

```
 <animate attributeName="display" begin="0" dur="10" calcMode="discrete"  fill="remove" additive="sum" keyTimes="0;0.5;1" values="inherit;none;inherit" />
 <animate attributeName="display" begin="0" dur="10" calcMode="discrete" fill="remove" additive="sum" keyTimes="0;0.2;.8;1" values="inherit;none;inherit;none" />
```

I like to know if display is the special attribute for animate? or it is a bug in those two browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display property is one of the "All other data types used in animatable attributes and properties" in the [table in the SVG specification that defines whether something is animatable](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/animate.html#Animatable)  and reading across the answer is "no", it's not additive.